# React to phonecall on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Is there any way of controlling an incoming phonecall on UWP? I'm looking for something like:
1. Get IncomingPhonecallEventHandler to attach
2. When triggered, be capable of:

```
phonecall.Accept();
phonecall.Decline();
phonecall.DeclineWithSMS();
```

All of this is a part of my android smartwatch project, so I need to be able to call and recieve calls as well.

**EDIT 1**
I know the PhoneCallManager class, but registering for CallStateChanged event returns object, which I don't know how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [PhoneCallManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn624832) and the [PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.callstatechanged.aspx).

You can also checkout [this example (in C#)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall) to see how to interact with the apis

---

If you want to be able to block and filter calls, you can checkout [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CommunicationBlockAndFilter), it has that capability.

If you want to send SMS, [this example has the code needed](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive)

However, I don't believe there is an API to answer phone calls at this time

Comment: I excactly know this class, but point 2. of my question is not done this way. This example does not show clearly what im looking for as well...